# Some error on simple javascript attribute change

Tags: javascript, css

Where is my error? Nothing happens on mouse on:

HTML

```
    <div id="spettacoli_div">
      <img class="spettacoli" src="grafica/spettacoli_di_sala.png" alt="spettacoli di sala" onmouseover="document.getElementById('spettacoli_di_sala_on').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('spettacoli_di_sala_on').style.display = 'hidden';"> 
     <div>
    <div id="spettacoli_on_div"> 
     <img class="spettacoli_on" id="spettacoli_di_sala_on" src="grafica/spettacoli_di_sala_on.png" alt="spettacoli di sala"> 
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.spettacoli_on {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    padding-left: 4.4%;
    width:19.4%;
    height:auto;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Its `visibility` vs `display`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hiding the element using the CSS `visibility`, but your JavaScript is toggling its `display` property.

Answer (score 0):

`hidden` is not a valid value for the `display`-attribute. Set `display:none` or use `visibility`.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
.spettacoli_on {
             float: left;
             position: relative;
             padding-left: 4.4%;
             width: 19.4%;
             height: auto;
             display: none;
         }


<div id="spettacoli_div">
      <img class="spettacoli" src="grafica/spettacoli_di_sala.png" alt="spettacoli di sala" onmouseover="document.getElementById('spettacoli_di_sala_on').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('spettacoli_di_sala_on').style.display = 'none';"> 
     <div>
    <div id="spettacoli_on_div"> 
     <img class="spettacoli_on" id="spettacoli_di_sala_on" src="grafica/spettacoli_di_sala_on.png" alt="spettacoli di sala"> 
    </div>
```